# define a constant Tron address in solidity

Tags: solidity, web3js, smart-contract-wallets

this is my solidity code :

```
address constant public erc20 = 0xdac917D0C6ae59216317e533CfB295bAfc452f08;
```

i want to change it to Tron address ( like this ) :

```
address constant public erc20 = TGA5QuuSEDi6TsLk4CffBqkYVk4oD9DMQ5 ;
```

but compiler does not allow using this format
would you please help me what to do ?
thanks

Comment: you probably need to transform it to uint256 and then use address(<uint256-of-transformed-tron-address>)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65860069/pass-constant-tron-address-in-solidity

Comment: @MajdTL thanks but this link is not solution for constant tron address but input argument in function (greet)